# The rank of indecomposable finite abelian 2-group

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\rank{rank}$Let $P$ be a finite $p$-group. The rank of $P$ is $\log_{p}|P/\Phi(P)|$ where $\Phi(P)$ is the Frattini subgroup of $P$, we write $\rank(P)=\log_{p}|P/\Phi(P)|$.

Let a finite group $A$ act faithfully on a finite $2$-group $G$.

An $A$-invariant subgroup $H$ is called a **$A$-direct factor** if there exists an $A$-invariant subgroup $K$ such that $G=H\times K$. If there are no proper nontrivial $A$-direct factors of $G$, then $G$ is said to be **$A$-indecomposable** (or **indecomposable** if $A=1$). The next $2$ results on the rank of $A$-indecomposable $2$-group are well-known.

- Assume $G$ is $A$-indecomposable abelian $2$-group. If $A=1$, then $\rank(G)=1$.
- Assume $G$ is $A$-indecomposable abelian $2$-group. If $\gcd(|A|,|G|)=1$, then $G$ is homocyclic (direct product of cyclic groups of the same order), also $\rank(G)$ is equal to the dimension of the irreducible $GF(2)[A]$-module $G/\Phi(G)$ ($GF(2)$ is the finite field of $2$ elements).

**Question** Assume $G$ is $A$-indecomposable abelian $2$-group. If $A$ is a cyclic finite $2$-group, then could we say something about $\rank(G)$?

**Easy version** Assume $G$ is $A$-indecomposable abelian $2$-group. If $A$ is a cyclic group of order $2$, then could we say something about $\rank(G)$?

Using linear algebra, one could determine $\rank(G)$ in **Easy version** when $G$ is elementary abelian, that is $\rank(G)=1$ or $2$.

Comment: Are you assuming that $G$ is abelian?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, I assume that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: In the case when $G$ is elementary abelian,  there is a result that says that the $2$-group $A$ has finite representation type (i.e. it has finitely many indecomposable modules over ${\mathbb F}_2$). if and only if $A$ is cyclic. So, I think the answer to your question in that case is that ${\rm rank}(G)$ is bounded if and only if $A$ is cyclic.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will edit my question by adding an assumption that $A$ is cyclic. Thanks very much. @DerekHolt